# Google MLKit Pose Detection with React Native

Tags: react-native, flutter, google-mlkit

I wanted came across this guide https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/pose-detection/classifying-poses and I wanted to develop a cross plateform app with pose classification using react native.
I haven't been able to find any wrapper from react-native ? Is this going to be developped one day ?
I thought about using the flutter one but it seems that it doesn't contain the pose detection library ?

Comment: Hi, there is no official support for mlkit react native plugins currently. You might be able to find such plugins supported by other parties.

Answer (score 2):

ML Kit itself does not currently have a plan to provide React Native or Flutter wrappers. Some developers have come up their own wrappers, e.g. https://pub.dev/packages/google_ml_kit. They are not officially endorsed by ML Kit and your mileage may vary.

Answer (score -2):

For React Native we have a wrapper for ML Kit https://github.com/a7medev/react-native-ml-kit but pose detection is not implemented yet.